# Should BufferedReaders be passed a dynamic FileReader?

Tags: java, performance, bufferedreader, filereader, java-io

As the question states, is passing a dynamic `FileReader` bad practice? Should this/can this `FileReader` be closed sufficiently?

```
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(
    new FileReader(new File("C:/Path/To/File.txt")));
.... do something
buffReader.close();
```

Should the `FileReader` also be closed? Would separation be required to do so?

Perhaps a simple question, but I'm not well versed in Java IO; so apologies if so. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is 'a dynamic `FileReader`'? Where in the Javadoc does it suggest any such limitation?  What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The dynamic `FileReader` is created within the `BufferedReader` methods arguments. I was debugging some elevated issues and this was picked up as not being closed correctly. As immibis has answered, this is in fact being closed correctly within the `BufferedReader`'s `close` method.

Comment: Also consider to use the Java NIO.2 File API. java.io.File is now considered legacy API.

Comment: The `FileReader` is being created within the `BufferedReader`'s *constructor* arguments. There's nothing startingly 'dynamic' about that that doesn't apply to any other object reference in Java. Don't just make up your own terminology and expect everybody else to understand it.

Comment: Apologies if you didn't understand that the element is dynamically created. I should have stated that it is created without being instantiated in a typical way with a reference to a variable or memory location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not necessary. `buffReader.close()` will close the FileReader as well.

For some reason, this doesn't seem to be mentioned in the Javadoc. However, if you look at the source code for `BufferedReader`, you'll find `close` is defined as:

```
public void close() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (in == null)
            return;
        in.close();
        in = null;
        cb = null;
    }
}
```

where `in` is the wrapped `Reader` (in this case a `FileReader`). Therefore, closing the `BufferedReader` closes the `FileReader` as well.

This is the case for all of the "wrappers" I'm aware of - `InputStream`s, `OutputStream`s, `Reader`s and `Writer`s, including things like `InputStreamReader`.